# Cardview is looking bad on emulator

Tags: android, layout, cardview

I am using some cardviews with layouts in it in my app.
On some devices (Xiaomi MI 9 SE Android 9, Galaxy Tab Active 2 Android 9) it looks pretty good and on other it doesn't (Emulator Pixel XL Android 9, Galaxy Tab 2 Android 7.
What is causing this optical issue?

**CardView in my layout**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cViewMail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_32sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_48sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_32sdp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_25sdp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vHeader">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cLayMailContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgMailLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_18sdp"
            android:alpha="0.3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etLoginusermail"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_18sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/usermail"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgMailLogo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Galaxy Tab 2 (Android 7.0)**
[image]

**Emulator Pixel XL (Android 9)**

[image]

**Xiaomi Mi 9 SE (Android 9)**

[image]

**Galaxy Tab Active 2 (Android 9)**

[image]

Comment: see below answer

Comment: and tell me is it working or not

Answer (score 0):

radius of cardview must be half of its height

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cViewMail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_32sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_48sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_32sdp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vHeader">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cLayMailContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgMailLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_18sdp"
            android:alpha="0.3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etLoginusermail"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_18sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/usermail"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgMailLogo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```